# "Must declare variable", but when I declare it, "variable already declared"

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm generating insert SQL which returns the primary key to the caller. The SQL is generated for an arbitrary table, so I can't use SCOPE_IDENTITY() because not every table uses an identity.
When I execute my query, MS SQL complains the output var is not declared, but says it's already declared when I declare it. Damned if I do, damned if I don't.

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("d", direction:ParameterDirection.Output, size:8000);
// (Add the input params a, b, c)
remoteConnection.Execute(sql, parameters);
```

SQL:

```
-- Error: Must declare the table variable "@d"
INSERT INTO Blacklist
(DatabaseConnectionId,TableSchema,TableName)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @d
VALUES (@a,@b,@c)
```

I declare the variable:

```
DECLARE @d int
INSERT INTO Blacklist
(DatabaseConnectionId,TableSchema,TableName)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @d
VALUES (@a,@b,@c)
-- Error: The variable name '@d' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `@d` as a `TABLE` variable:

```
DECLARE @d TABLE
(
    id INT
);

INSERT INTO Blacklist
(DatabaseConnectionId,TableSchema,TableName)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @d
VALUES (@a,@b,@c)
```